# How to calculate CIDR for desired host?

Tags: ip-address, cidr

I would like to explain with an example.

If I am right, the IP range of 20.0.0.0/24 is as follows:

- CIDR Range: 20.0.0.0/24
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Wildcard Bits: 0.0.0.255
- First IP:    20.0.0.0
- Last IP:     20.0.0.255
- Total Host: 256

Also if I am right, we can assign any IP between 20.0.0.0 and 20.0.0.255 to a host or a host can get any IP between 20.0.0.0 and 20.0.0.255.

If I want address spaces and CIDR for limited hosts e.g. between 10-12 hosts, can I calculate Address Spaces/ CIDR for such requirements? If yes, how to calculate?

Comment: You can find many CIDR calculators online, such as http://cidr.xyz

Comment: The link http://cidr.xyz/ is helpful to find IP range of a CIDR format. The example I explained says, total number of host is 256. I am looking for a calculation or a link so that I can find a CIDR having total number of host is 15 in its IP range. I hope I explained well.

Comment: But the number of hosts can only be a power of 2

Comment: Okay. For 256 hosts, I believe, its 2⁸ = 2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2 = 256. Ignore 15 hosts. For 16 hosts, I believe, it should be 2⁴ = 2×2×2×2 = 16. Now how to calculate CIDR format for total hosts for 2⁴?

Comment: This one can be helpful for quick tests if you want to convert cidr to Ip and have info such as nr of hosts, and then back from IPs to CIDR 20.0.0.0/24 https://www.ipconvertertools.com

Answer (score 0):

To get the CIDR containing *N* number of hosts, use `2⁵ - log₂N`. I wrote a quick calculator [Run it]:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({target: {value}}) => {
  document.querySelector('output').textContent =
    2**5 - Math.log2(Number(value));
});
```

```html
Hosts: <input type="number" />
CIDR: /<output></output>
```